# Service calling itself with AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have an app that calls a `Service` with the `AlarmManager` on the main activity and inside that `Service` makes another alarm to call itself moments after. The alarm in the main activity works fine but the alarm in the `Service` doesn't set off. Anyone know why?

This is the alarm in my main activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, DailyLogsService.class);

    Calendar time=Calendar.getInstance();
    time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,13);

    time.set(Calendar.MINUTE,15);
    time.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    AlarmManager alarmM=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pending= PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),0,i,0);
    //alarmM.cancel(pending);
    alarmM.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pending);
    Toast.makeText(this, "STARTING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and this is the alarm on my service

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {


    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DailyLogsService.class);
    Calendar time=Calendar.getInstance();

    time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    time.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
    time.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    AlarmManager alarmM=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pending= PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),0,i,0);
    alarmM.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pending);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your alarm code in `onCreate` of the `Service` to `onStartCommand` method.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DailyLogsService.class);
    Calendar time=Calendar.getInstance();
    time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    time.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
    time.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    AlarmManager alarmM=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pending= PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),0,i,0);
    alarmM.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pending);

    return START_NON_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much sir! :D im pretty new to this so i really dont know what to do.. anyways thanks again :D